# how to stream text from a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get text on click of a hyperlink. I want to load this text into a div on my webpage.

```
var main = document.getElementById("main");
main.innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data='+$(this).attr('href')+'></object>';
```

This loads the entire web page in my main div. I want only the text. I am using JavaScript or Jquery? I have stopped page redirection on link click as I want to load textContent on current web page

Is it possible to stream text from given link?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Especially I have no idea what "streaming text" is in the context of a website or link.

Comment: if there are any tags in the intended web page , for example <b>abc</b> or some image tags then I want just the abc and no tags no images, videos etc. only the text content

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the page is on the same domain and  the target section on the page has an id of `target` for example

**Other page:**

```
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <div id="target">some content you want to import</div>
</body>
```

You can acheve what you want like this:

**Your page:**

```
<script>

$('a#yourLinkId').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // prevents browser from following the link 
     $('#main').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #target');
     //                                      ^ 
     //                                      This space is required
});                                            

</script>
```

What's actually happening is you're calling:

```
 $('#main').load('yourdomain.com/yourpage #target');
```

Which will load the div with the id `target` from the other page into `$('#main')`

You can read more about how it works here:

[jQuery.load()#loading-page-fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: doesn't work. I feel it is very easy but I am missing out something. The page is navigating away from current location. I don't want that. Also I am not supposed to change any html files present. I am supposed to work only in js file to get the result.

Comment: P.S. to add to: (I know it's for explanatory purpose only, but) keep in mind that `#yourLinkId` is a faster selector than `a#yourLinkId`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan indeed, it was there to help explain the selector targets the anchor, good point though and thanks for the improvement to the answer